# WebDriver / Can I identify DOM changes by WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, xpath

I trying to get all elements which were changed After I click on element.

I try to do the next:

```
List<WebElement> lstWeb = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*");
driver.findElement(By.id("ImprBtn"));
List<WebElement> lstWebAfter = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*");
lstWebAfter.removeAll(lstWeb );
```

The problem is that it's taking a long time, because in each list I have more than 800 WebElements.

There is an efficient way to identify changes in DOM after I click on element?

Answer (score 0):

In general, i think it's not good approach (comparing the whole DOM before and after some operation) for designing your test cases, it's probably happens because not 100% correct design of the cases.

Design your tests cases more carefully, prepare your expected result and the expected DOM changes (i.e. the change in the webapp) and compare them to the actual result.

To learn more about recommended design of automation please read about the [PageObjects](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) Pattern.
You can find nice implementation for it [here](http://dojofloripa.wordpress.com/2008/04/20/como-usar-tdd-e-page-objects-para-construir-interfaces-web/) (don't mind the language, just read the code :)).

If you still need solution to identify DOM changes, check those solutions:

1. [Mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/MutationObserver).
2. Check this DOM monitoring [suggestions](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/monitoring-dom-properties/).
3. More about [mutation events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents) (recommended by W3 for what you looking for).

Comment: I create page generator. For that, I want to get all elements which changes my DOM, and have an effect on it. I use WebDriver to scan all these elements.

Comment: That's what you said in the q, i get it :) It's a bad practice. Please read carefully my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You should narrow down the xpath query in order to more efficiently search the DOM.

If you're not very comfortable with raw xath, I have a helper library that let's you create xpath based on LINQ-esq syntax.

Sharing a link in case you find it helpful

http://www.unit-testing.net/CurrentArticle/How-to-Create-Xpath-From-Lambda-Expressions.html